# Is openssl is an alias for libressl on macOS?

Tags: macos, command-line, mac, openssl, license

I have no idea why despite having (seemingly) `openssl`, when I run:

`openssl version`

it outputs:

LibreSSL 3.3.6

And when I run `which openssl` and `type openssl` to check whether or not `openssl` is just an alias for `libressl` the output points me to `openssl`'s binaries:

/usr/bin/openssl

Running `ls /usr/bin/ | grep libressl` returns nonzero which means libressl isn't installed.

Furthermore, `man openssl` actually displays the man page for the `openssl` command.

So what's going on with `openssl version`? Why is it outputting LibreSSL 3.3.6 despite what I have installed actually being OpenSSL? I know that LibreSSL is a fork of OpenSSL, but why would the binaries of the ORIGINAL OpenSSL have any reference to its fork when running the `version` argument on the CLI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `openssl` binary shipped with macOS is actually `libressl` and not OpenSSL

It's not just an Alias or Symlink, but the `/usr/bin/openssl` file itself is actually LibreSSL, there is no `libressl` to run (because the `openssl` is it.)

Comment: Although Libre is a fork, it deliberately keeps, with exceptions only when considered necessary, the same API for programs AND interactive interface including the program _name_ `openssl`. This was/is to make it easy for people, and scripts and tools and systems, formerly using OpenSSL to switch to Libre, which was/is their goal.

Comment: Ah I understand now, thank  you  @dave_thompson_085 and Yisroel  Tech